# fixed в absolute изменение позиционирования

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  if ($('#sideBar').offset().top + $('#sideBar').height() >= $('#liveCommentsBlock').offset().top) {
    $('#sideBar').css("position", "absolute");
  }
};
```

```css
#main {
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: 15%;
}
#cont {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}
#mainContent {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 80%;
}
#mainContentArt {
  width: 86%;
  margin-left: 7%;
}
.article {
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  background: black;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
#sideBar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 18%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: 17%;
}
#liveCommentsBlock {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: #FCEFFC;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div id="cont">
    <div id="mainContent">
      <div id="mainContentArt">
        <div class="article"></div>
        <div class="article"></div>
        <div class="article"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="sideBar">
      <div id="sideBarMenu"></div>
      <div id="sideBarSub"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="spacer" style="clear: both;"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="liveCommentsBlock">
    <p>##COMMENTS##</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Суть в том, что блок `#sideBar` после прокрутки до определенного места, должен "останавливаться" там. Однако пока что, он останавливается, но смещается в верхний левый угол блока `#cont`. Как это поправить?

Comment: А `position` установить в конце в `fixed` с нужными координатами не пробовали? .....на одних `relative` и `absolute` свет клином не сошелся

Comment: разве `fixed`, не заставляет его следовать за scroll'ом?

Comment: А где тут в примере `liveCommentsBlock` кстати? ......`+660` это типа на каком расстоянии liveCommentsBlock?))

Comment: Алексей, этот блок находится под блоком `cont`, а `660` - есть высота блока `sideBar`, так как значения `.offset().bottom` - не существует.

Comment: лучше добавьте разметку полностью.... ибо сейчас ваш js не валиден ибо нет элемента, к которому применяется..а на словах - мало ли где он там может быть.....`660` заменяется банально на `someElement.height` чтоб не было магических чисел

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pпопробуйте отслеживать по `scroll`:

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  
  if(window.pageYOffset + 100< $('#liveCommentsBlock').offset().top ){
    $('#sideBar').removeAttr('style');
      $('#sideBar').css("position", "fixed");
      
  }else  {
     var x = $('#sideBar').offset().top;
     var y = $('#sideBar').offset().left;
    $('#sideBar').css("position", "absolute");
    $('#sideBar').offset({top:x, left:y}).top;
  } 
};
```

```css
#main {
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: 15%;
}
#cont {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}
#mainContent {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 80%;
}
#mainContentArt {
  width: 86%;
  margin-left: 7%;
}
.article {
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  background: black;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
#sideBar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 18%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: 17%;
  color:red;
}
#liveCommentsBlock {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: #FCEFFC;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div id="cont">
    <div id="mainContent">
      <div id="mainContentArt">
        <div class="article"></div>
        <div class="article"></div>
        <div class="article"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="sideBar">
      <div id="sideBarMenu">ehethethterh</div>
      <div id="sideBarSub">ethethethethert</div>
    </div>
    <div class="spacer" style="clear: both;"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="liveCommentsBlock">
    <p>##COMMENTS##</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Подскажите, зачем нужен `+100` в `window.pageYOffset + 100`? Вроде бы все работает, я попробую использовать ваш вариант в проекте. Но ответ на вопрос все таки хотелось бы узнать.

Comment: Eсли не добавлять 100пх топ ваш фиксированный блок уйдет под блок комментариев, что не очень правельно. А так он останавлевается раньше, чем позиция scroll равняется с top блока коментариев.